# MODX: I cannot send files using FormIt

Tags: forms, modx, modx-revolution, formit

I am trying to send a file from my form, but I receive only the name of the file. According to this [article](http://codingpad.maryspad.com/2011/03/09/modx-revolution-adding-an-attachment-field-to-a-formit-form/) it seems that I have done the things properly, but in the end I get only the file's name.

```
<input type="file" name="files" value="[[!+fi.files]]"/> // form's field
[[+files]] // calling in &emailTpl
```

Perhaps, I have to do some transformation, but I have no idea...

There is a chunk including

```
[[!FormIt?
&hooks=`recaptchav2,spam,email`
&emailTo=`[[#1.mailto]]`
&emailFrom=`[[#1.mailfrom]]`
&emailSubject=`Заявка на расчет с сайта [[++site_url]]`
&emailTpl=`401-calculate-project-tpl`
&successMessage=`1`
&clearFieldsOnSuccess=`1`
&errTpl=`[[+error]]`
&validate=`email-3:required`
]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a trouble in a version of FormIt. I should update it to 3.0.3, so I envolved this trouble. Congratulation.